# HTML change cursor flying upon area

Tags: html, cursor, area

it's a me Mar... again!
I have a problem with my cursor.
I have an image on which I have a map area.

My wish is to be able to have a modified cursor on the image

```
.dragme {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5;
    cursor:move;
}
```

(it works). But when I want to have a modified cursor on area (from map), it doesn't work.
I tried to do :

```
area {
    cursor:hand;
    disabled="disabled"
}
```

(I saw disabled="disabled" somewhere) but it doesn't work nor just cursor:hand.
I also tried to put this line in each area,

```
    <area title="P96N-P-1" shape="circle" coords="808,476,16" href="www.google.com" style="cursor:hand;" target="_blank" >
    <area title="P96N-P-2" shape="circle" coords="874,882,8" href="www.google.com" style="cursor:hand;">
    <area title="P96N-P-3" shape="circle" coords="924,1424,8" href="www.google.com" style="cursor:hand;">
```

but it appears that nothing works and I can't modify my cursor when I fly upon an area.

Do someone of you have an idea?

Comment: please make a fiddle or jsbin file with the relevant code for your issue. plus, your CSS codes are not corret....

Comment: I made modifications on my CSS, I will make a fiddle when i'll have the time :)